# Why printing time does not decrease using processes in this program?

Tags: process, printf, tty

I'm making a program in C on CentOS using processes, and am trying to print the numbers from 0 to 1000000 in two different terminals in the shortest time possible. But time increased twice compared to printing on a single terminal. In a single terminal takes 6 or 7 seconds to print, with the two terminals takes 12-13 seconds. Is there any reason why this happens?

```
main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    pid_t pid;
    time_t t1,t2;
    time(&t1);
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        int x;
        FILE *da1=fopen("/dev/pts/2","w+");
        for(x=0;x<=1000000;x++)
            fprintf(da1,"%d ",x);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int y;
        FILE *da2=fopen("/dev/pts/3","w+");
        for(y=0;y<=1000000;y++)
        fprintf(da2,"%d ",y);
    }
    wait(0);
    time(&t2);
    printf("\nTime %i\n",t2-t1);
}
```

Comment: As far as I know `printf()` is a blocking function, so whenever one process writes to the terminal, the other one has to wait for stdout to become available again